# Javascript tasklist (adding delete functionality)

Tags: javascript

I'm working on improving my vanilla javascript. I'm trying to get this delete button to work. I don't know what is blocking it. I can't even click on and get the event.target of the button or trash can. It only clicks on the 'li'.

I've tried putting the delete functionality into a separate function of it's own but then I couldn't loop through the added tasks.  I'm open to methods with adding an id or without needing an id.

```js
const todoInputEl = document.querySelector('.todo__input');
const todoListEl = document.querySelector('.todo__list');
const todoItemEls = document.querySelectorAll('.todo__item');


function addListItem() {
  todoInputEl.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      let newListItem = createListItem(todoInputEl.value);
      todoListEl.insertBefore(newListItem, todoListEl.childNodes[0]);
      todoInputEl.value = '';
    }
    const deleteButtonEls = document.querySelectorAll('.delete-task');
    for (let i = 0; i < deleteButtonEls.length; i++) {

      deleteButtonEls.addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.parentNode.remove(e);
      })
    }
  })
};

function createListItem(text) {
  const newListElement = document.createElement('li');
  newListElement.innerHTML = `
        <span class="task-text">${text}</span>
        <button class="delete-task">Delete<i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
        `;
  newListElement.setAttribute("class", "todo__item");
  return newListElement;
};


function toggleDone() {
  todoListEl.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log(event)
    if (event.target.classList.contains('todo__item')) {
      event.target.classList.toggle('done');
    }
  })
};


addListItem();
toggleDone();
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="todo">
    <div class="todo__header">
      <h1 class="todo__title">to-do's</h1>
      <label for="todo input">
          <input class="todo__input" type="text" placeholder="enter a todo">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="todo__body">
      <ul class="todo__list">
        <!-- <li class="todo__item">Do your laundry</li>
                        <li class="todo__item">Create a video</li>
                        <li class="todo__item">Edit video content</li> -->
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>java
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: deleteButtonEls.addEventListener is not a function` see: "[what do `querySelectorAll()` and `getElementsBy*` methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)"

Answer (score 1):

your `deleteButtonEls` is firing off every time you have a keypress event

and its returning:

```
"TypeError: deleteButtonEls.addEventListener is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous>"
```

EDIT(Fixed): not sure if this is what your looking for but this works

```js
const todoInputEl = document.querySelector('.todo__input');
const todoListEl = document.querySelector('.todo__list');
const todoItemEls = document.querySelectorAll('.todo__item');


function addListItem() {
  todoInputEl.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      let newListItem = createListItem(todoInputEl.value);
      todoListEl.insertBefore(newListItem, todoListEl.childNodes[0]);
      todoInputEl.value = '';
    }

  })
};

function deleteListItem(target){
  const x = target.getElementsByClassName('delete-task')
  
  x[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
        target.remove();
      })
}
function createListItem(text) {
  const newListElement = document.createElement('li');
  newListElement.innerHTML = `
        <span class="task-text">${text}</span>
        <button class="delete-task">Delete<i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
        `;
  newListElement.setAttribute("class", "todo__item");
  deleteListItem(newListElement)
  return newListElement;
};


function toggleDone() {
  todoListEl.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
//     console.log(event)
    if (event.target.classList.contains('todo__item')) {
      event.target.classList.toggle('done');
    }
  })
};


addListItem();
toggleDone();
```

this passes the created element to `deleteListItem()` after you set the attribute `todo__item` to it

gets the class with `'delete-task'` and sets a event listener on the element which is the button with that class name

on click it removes the whole element

your `toggleDone()` function never worked comment if you need help with that didn't want to fix something you want to try on yourself

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm not sure I understand how this [0] index works. x[0].addEventListener('click', function() {...                                                                                          I changed it to loop through all the tasks. It makes more sense to me.  for(let i=0; i<itemsToDelete.length; i++) {
        itemsToDelete[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            console.log(target);
            target.remove();
        })   The toggleDone() works for me.  Maybe I changed some code around after I posted the question.

Comment: when you use ```getElementsByClassName``` it returns a ```HTMLCollection``` of elements, which is an array-like object. in order to access it and get the first item from it we use index 0 if you don't tell which index to get it will return the whole array-like object instead